# Unable to install MariaDB on Debian 7

Tags: debian, mysql, debian-wheezy, mariadb

I'm trying to install MariaDB on my Debian 7 development machine and I've hit a problem.

Following this [tutorial](http://www.x2q.net/blog/2013/05/05/howto-install-mariadb-on-debian-7-slash-wheezy/), and this [workaround](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-3882), I enter this command:

> sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-5.5
>   libmysqlclient18=5.5.30-mariadb1~wheezy

And Debian gives me the following error:

> E: Version '5.5.28-mariadb1~wheezy' for 'libmysqlclient18' was not
>   found

I've used this tutorial before for another Debian 7 install, but I never encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Partially an answer, and premising that the tutorial is a link rot now, and premising that this question is very old and never answered, and so it's nearly impossible to help you. But...

Debian is famous for its stability, but because they strongly recommends to:

- do not follow online tutorials found on the web
- and, do not mix Debian repositories with online repositories

I've found this official documentation particularly useful at the beginning to understand why it's so important to do not mix repositories and versions in Debian:

https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

In particular, this section:

https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

So, whatever was your problem, in the future, on Debian, it's better to first decide what software you want to have, and then, choosing the distribution that provides that. In this way, you have no need to adopt different versions, and you dramatically increase stability, and you reduce your risks to obtain a FrankenDebian.

Anyway, if all of this does not apply to you, always just try a simple `apt-get update` before installing things. That may solve similar errors. But probably that was not the solution to the reported problem. Since you were probably already aware of this.